# How to change the default text of the file input with reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, jsx

I have an input file on my jsx, and I want to change the text "Choisir un fichier" and "Aucun fichier choisi"

My code is :

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label className="control-label col-sm-2" ><strong>Site - Logo (150 x 30px)</strong></label>
    <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" className="form-control-file" onChange={this.handleImgLogoChange} style={{border:'.1rem solid #d9d9d9', borderRadius:'.2rem'}}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run it, I get:

[image]

How to change the default text of input file ?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, we are talking about `input` styling. If this is an `input`, then the `placeholder` is responsible for it. Look here, see if it helps. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp)

Comment: @al-bulat I talk about the text of the button of the standard input file

Answer (score 2):

```
        <div style={{width: 80, height: 80, border: '1px solid red', position: 'relative'}}>
          <label for='file' style={{position: 'absolute', width: 80, height: 80, cursor: 'pointer'}}>select file</label>
          <input id='file' type='file' onChange={this.handleFileUpload} style={{opacity: 0}} />
        </div>
```

maybe like this?

u can check online demo on [stackblitz demo](https://react-um1u8c.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I talk about the text of the button of the standard input file

Comment: first,  the input type of file is not change the default text, u must use another way to emulator the text of button of the standard input file